# Is it possible to use inheritance with JGraph

Tags: java, inheritance, graph, jgrapht

I have a graph declared as

```
Graph<MyBase, DefaultEdge> myGraph = new DefaultGraph<MyBase, DefaultEdge>();
```

I want to be able to keep the graph and edges and replace the base class types of vertices with the subtypes , something like

```
for (Mybase mybase : myGraph.vertexSet()) {
   mybase = mySubType;
}
```

But I dont think this works, the type pf the vertices remains MyBase. Is this something that I can achieve with jGraph? The following does not seem to work

```
public static <Object, DefaultEdge> void replaceVertex(
      Graph<MyBase, org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge> graph, MyBase vertex,
      MyBase replace) {

    graph.addVertex(replace);
    for (org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge edge : graph.outgoingEdgesOf(vertex))
      graph.addEdge(replace, graph.getEdgeTarget(edge), edge);
    for (org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge edge : graph.incomingEdgesOf(vertex))
      graph.addEdge(graph.getEdgeSource(edge), replace, edge);
    graph.removeVertex(vertex);


  }
```

When `replace` is teh base class type this works fine, when `replace` is the sub type then a vertex is lost. How can I make this work?

Comment: You are assigning value to a local loop variable that is immediately discarded. What exactly are you trying to achieve? You want to substitute vertices in the graph? What do you mean by "replace the base class"? Java has type erasure, so at runtime it doesn't even know what the type of vertices are anymore.

Comment: yes I want to substitute the vertices , hoe can I achieve that

Answer (score 0):

```
Graph<Number,DefaultEdge> g = new DefaultGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
Double mydouble=new Double(5.0);
Integer myInteger=new Integer(4);
g.add(myDouble);
g.add(myInteger);
```

This works fine: here, the vertex type is a super type of Integer and Double.

Comment: I am trying to replace the vertices of base class with class but instead of replacing it just deletes it , I added the code to the question